# How to search and replace values in a file with elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a file in which I need to change some specific set of values with other set of values. What is the elixir-way of doing that ?

e.g.

```
I love ruby.
I love elixir.
I like javascript.
I am trying to write a program in some language.
That some language can be elixir or ruby.
```

Now here if I want to change the value of `some language` on 5th line, with `elixir`, how can I do it with elixir ?

I also want to change the value of `like` with `love`.

How we do this in elixir ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Try to use laravel-elixir-replace plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = """
I love ruby.
I love elixir.
I like javascript.
I am trying to write a program in some language.
That some language can be elixir or ruby.
"""

str = String.replace(str, "some language", "elixir", global: true )
str = String.replace(str, "like", "love", global: true )
```

Comment: But that will change the value in all the places. We just need to change it in line 5.

Comment: you need to add global: true as the final parameter - I've edited above to show you how

Comment: String.replace(str, "in some language", "in elixir", global: true )

Answer (score 1):

You could use [File.stream!/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/File.html#stream!/3) to read a file line by line and handle these lines as Enumerable.